# Child to parent communication with nlog MDLC

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, nlog

We have a set of web services using ASP.NET 5 with .NET 5. Their signatures are imposed by an external entity, and they all have a few common parameters that we would like to log on every log line.

However, some of these parameters are specified differently for each service (some in POST data, some in query string...). And we have to fetch some data from a database with an async call in order to translate some of those into something worthy of being logged.

We are using nlog MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext (MDLC) inside an ASP.NET filter to initialise the MDLC with a few common parameters. This filter also does a few other things, such as log the end of call. And for those parameters which are not common between services we call an async method in every service controller which will validate and translate them from the database (hence the async nature). If we set the MDLC inside this method (which would be cool as we want to avoid duplicate code), it does not work since the MDLC is AsyncLocal - allowing no communication from child to parent context (AFAIK).

The question is: how could we make sur the values found by the async method are used inside the end log message created by the filter? Therefore a child to parent "bubble up" of MDLC values?

Comment: Think the work-around is to use `HttpContext.Items` and then use [${aspnet-item}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetItem-layout-renderer) to output the values where needed. But initializeing a special parent-scope-dictionary where sub-tasks can insert their own properties for the parent to see, that sounds like a nice feature. Feel free to create a pull-request for the NLog-project.

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/4643

Comment: @RolfKristensen Thanks for the link, I've added an implementation idea to that ticket and may do it in the future should this question prove fruitless.